# Video is not showing in page when linked locally but shows up when the source is a URL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

So I was practicing some basic stuff on a cloud IDE called Goorm and I wanted to create a simple page showing a video I upload directly to the server, the ejs file and the video are in the same folder however if i set the src of the video tag as "media/dog.webm" the video does not show up and is just blank instead, but if i set the source to a online URL where the video is uploaded and can be acessed it loads.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
        DOG
    </h1>
    <video autoplay id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="https://somewebsite.com/dog.webm" type="video/webm" >
        Your browser shall not play this video
    </video>
<div/>
```

This code works but I have almost no idea why when src is "media/dog.webm" or "dog.webm" do not work, I've tried setting the source as the complete directory, in the home folder and in the same directory as the .ejs file and .js file. I belive somewhow when I run "node index.js" it has no acess to media content so it cannot load locally stored media content to the page made in the .ejs file

The code that I was expecting to work the code below, it works if i write it into a html in my machine but doesn't when Goorm runs it from the ejs. I'm 99% sure it's just a stupid small thing i am missing but I can't find a solution anywhere.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
        DOG
    </h1>
    <video autoplay id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="media/dog.webm" type="video/webm" >
        Your browser shall not play this video
    </video>
<div/>
```

Some more info, other simple ejs that do not load media files do show without problems. I am running at port 3000. Ejs version is 3.1.2, Express version is 4.17.1. NodeJS version is v10.16.3. Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS x86_64.

edit: adding below the .js file i am running on nodejs

```
let express = require("express")
let app = express()

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home.ejs")
})

app.get("/ovo/:coisa", function(req, res){
    let ags = req.params.coisa
    res.render("ogs.ejs", {coisaVar: ags})
})

app.get("/dog", function(req, res){
    res.render("dog.ejs")
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server has started!")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serve your static files (images, fonts, videos) just like that. You are using a server (node.js) and browser will request the static files on the html and your server will serve them individually.

So first step create a `public` folder inside root of your project. Inside the public directory move your video.

And now configure express.js to serve whatever in your public directory.

```js
let express = require("express")
let app = express()

// this is the line express is waiting for to serve your video !!!
app.use(express.static('public'))


app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home.ejs")
})

app.get("/ovo/:coisa", function(req, res){
    let ags = req.params.coisa
    res.render("ogs.ejs", {coisaVar: ags})
})

app.get("/dog", function(req, res){
    res.render("dog.ejs")
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server has started!")
})
```

This is the doc, you should take a look. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

All good now try to access your video as `/media/dog.webm` in your html. Let me know how it goes. Good luck

Comment: alrigth so I created the folder "public" inside my project's folder so the directory to it is "/projectA/public" and all the other stuff are inside /projectA too, express, ejs and the code files.

i started the server with your new code and set the source to "public/dog.webm" but still getting nothing where the video should show up

Comment: `src="/media/dog.webm"`     do not write public

Comment: another thing, if i try to go directly to the file by acessing the URL of my project at "https://testurl.com/public/dog.webm" i get a page saying "Cannot GET /public/dog.webm"

Comment: FINALLY! it worked when i put the media folder with the video inside at the "public" folder, that was it. thanks

Comment: @LuanA. Nice to hear it is working. Please give me a vote up. :)

Comment: I just voted up but as I do not have 15 reputation yet it does not change the publicly displayed post score, I hope that's okay for you

Comment: @LuanA. :)  it is okey. Take care

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`"./media/"` relative path , otherwise it will try going to the document root.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
        DOG
    </h1>
    <video autoplay id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="./media/dog.webm" type="video/webm" >
        Your browser shall not play this video
    </video>
<div/>
```

Comment: No success, I can see in the loaded page HTML the " src="./media/dog.webm" " but still renders nothing.

I've tried too "./dog.webm" and "dog.webm" again but nothing

Comment: Is there a document root URL specified in your application that it forces src references to or .htacess rules  / web.config rules?

Comment: in my running .js file i specify nothing forcing src references, but there are options for how i want to run the nodejs such as adding Run Options and Source Path but i believe that does not affect it, you can see more here at the Goorm guide https://help.goorm.io/en/goormide/02.project/build-run-configuration